# NoMethodError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Please help me. I'm not sure if I have a problem with routes, or plural, but this error occurs and no longer know what to do, already researched in many places and nothing.

I started a mini tutorial to devise and it worked, the login works. So I would like to reuse it and build a to-do list.

When I put a partial render to where I would like them to stay the fields to create a to-do list, occurs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
1: <%= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
2:     <% if @todo_list.errors.any? %>
3:         <div id="error_explanation">
4:           <h2><%= pluralize(@todo_list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this todo_list from being saved:</h2>
```

Routes:

```
 match 'dashboard' => 'home#dashboard'
 match 'register' =>'registration#register'
 root :to => 'home#index'
```

---

```
    new_member_session GET    /members/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            member_session POST   /members/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_member_session DELETE /members/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           member_password POST   /members/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_member_password GET    /members/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_member_password GET    /members/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                           PUT    /members/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_member_registration GET    /members/cancel(.:format)        registration#cancel
       member_registration POST   /members(.:format)               registration#create
   new_member_registration GET    /members/sign_up(.:format)       registration#new
  edit_member_registration GET    /members/edit(.:format)          registration#edit
                           PUT    /members(.:format)               registration#update
                           DELETE /members(.:format)               registration#destroy
                 dashboard        /dashboard(.:format)             home#dashboard
                  register        /register(.:format)              registration#register
                      root        /                                home#index
```

Model:

```
class ToDoList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :is_favorite, :name, :description
  has_many :tasks,  dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :member
```

Controller:

```
class ToDoListController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todo_lists = ToDoList.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @todo_lists }
    end
  end


  def new
    @todo_list = ToDoList.new

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # new.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @todo_list }
   end
 end
```

Comment: `@todo_list` is nil. Are you defining it for the view you are rendering?

Comment: Ya. When I run the debug @todo_list is null even, but do not understand why if it appears to be being called the right way:. (Well, in this view:

`<% if member_signed_in? %>

    <%= render partial: 'to_do_lists/to_do_list' %>
    <%= link_to "Saída", destroy_member_session_path, :method => :delete %>
`

and partial:

`<%= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
    <% if @todo_list.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
..`

Comment: where are you defining it to not be nil?

Comment: Well, it ends up being null because it was not created anything yet:(. I wanted the partial open the new. The error is probably dumb, but I noticed and I find the reason..@sevenseacat

Comment: What happens when you do form_for(ToDoList.new)  instead?

Comment: @railsdevmtl, It works if I comment a block of code that comes down:
`    <% if @todo_list.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@todo_list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this todo_list from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @todo_list.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
 <% end %>
`
the 'errors' of an error on all lines that appear: undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass. This void, but I can see after. But calling the direct model is not a bad practice?

Comment: Your view page belongs to which action? i mean what is your view file name?

Comment: @Pavan, the file view I call this @ todo_list is a partial called '_to_do_list.html.erb' and is inside a folder in the folder view called 'to_do_lists'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

Renaming Controller to:

class ToDoListsController

Also Change your file names and directory names accordingly.

Comment: "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" persists. :(.

Comment: Did you stop and restart your server ?

Comment: What are your file names?

Comment: ya, I'm always restarting when I move in controllers. The names are:

_to_do_lists_controller.rb_ controller
_to_do_list.rb_ model
_index.html.erb_ view that has the 'render'
_'_to_do_list.html.erb'_ partial

Comment: push the whole thing to git if you're still having trouble, i can take a look

Comment: your templates are missing, run touch app/views/to_do_lists/new.html.erb , you also need index.html.erb dont render partials until you have a better understanding of rails